# Where does the normal vector come from in this Stokes theorem problem?

Tags: stokes-theorem

I have this stokes theorem problem but my book doesn't clearly explain to me how the normal vector comes about. Here is the problem:

$$F = [y,z,x]$$ and S is this parabaloid:

[image]

So I guess z when expressed as a function of x and y = $1 - (x^2 + y^2)$. Why is this?

So parametrically it seems like the circle can be expressed as: $r(s) = [cos(s), sin(s), 0]$ because z = 0 and it's a circle. So $r'(s) = [-sin(s), cos(s), 0]$ So $$F(r(s)) = [\sin{s}, 0, \cos{s}]$$

Is that right os far?

But then I see the normal vector is $[2x, 2y, 1]$. Why is this?

PRoblem is here:

[image]

[image]

Why is this defined as the normal vector?

Comment: The normal vector $(2x,2y,1)$ comes from the gradient of the function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z$, and $S$ is the graph of solution set $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\ |\ f=1\}$.

Comment: @MathLover $|r_u\times r_v|$ is not a vector.  So it is not a normal vector.  Rather, the vector surface differential $\hat n dS$, where $\hat n$ is the unit normal to the surface,  is given by $$\hat n dS=\left(\frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial u} \times \frac{\partial \vec r}{\partial v}\right)\,du\,dv$$

Comment: @MarkViola of course! I meant $r_u \times r_v$. I just realized I changed that to magnitude. The point I was making to OP is that he can do that and get the same result if that is how he is used to.

Comment: Anyway repeating my question with correction, how do you usually find the normal vector? Parametrize and take cross product of  $\vec{r}_u × \vec{r}_v$?

Comment: @MathLover And upon normalization, one finds the unit normal.   One may then ask about the orientation.

Comment: @MarkViola finding unit normal is not necessary here. As far as orientation, the question clearly calls that out. But it all depends on where OP is at and where his confusion is. I don't know any of that till he responds.